# How to update adapter?

Tags: android, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I have several spinners in a class.
For the first spinner I have set of data.
Other spiners will download data from server according to the selection of the fist spinner.
However, after downloading data, it does not update the spinner adapters.

Adapter for the second spinner:

```
sectionField = new String[] {"Error"};
            adapterSection = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sectionField);
            adapterSection
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            section.setAdapter(adapterSection);
```

Code sample from fisrts spinner `onItemSelected`, which I believe should update the adapter:

```
sectionField = new String[data.length()];
sectionField = data;
section.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
adapterSection.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: `adapterSection.clear(); adapterSection.addAll(data);`

Comment: so `data` has not elements ...

Comment: now got it to work thanks. Should it be mentioned that adapter.clear() will work only if any kind of list was given to adapter?

Comment: post your comment as the answer, you were first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clean your adapter, then add items and notify.

```
adapterSection.clear();
adapterSection.addAll(data);
adapterSection.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope it's help.

Comment: +1 in "Reading Comments" skill ... and ... +2 in "Rewrite other user comments as an Answer" skill... you have advanced to next  level ... `adapterSection.notifyDataSetChanged();` ? what for ? it's already called in `addAll` ...